# Chrome: submitting a blob as input[type="file"]?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, blob

I'm making a Chrome extension that should send MHTML blob to a given URL. It works fine with FormData and XMLHttpRequest2, but I want to add an option to open upload result in new tab.

And thats the point where I've got stuck. I didn't find any way to create input[type="file"] from Blob instance and there's no way to open XMLHttpRequest2 response in separate tab or at least I didn't find any.

My question is: are there any ways to open a page either with result of XMLHttpRequest2, create a tab with given FormData, URL and method instead of just GETting URL request or am I doing it all wrong and there's some another way?

Comment: hunh? If you passed the blob to the page through form data, couldn't you just set the src of an element to said blob?
If what you are ultimately asking is "how can I modify the value of an input type file", you cannot. That would pose a security risk to users who don't want their files uploaded to the web.
Other than that, I don't find your question to be very clear. Maybe provide us with an example link or some code from what you've tried.

Comment: I didn't pass anything, there's chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML which gives blob